# SonarQube cannot access PostgresDB

Tags: postgresql, docker, jdbc, docker-compose, sonarqube

I am trying to set up SonarQube self-hosted using docker with docker-compose. To use SonarQube via HTTPS I am using nginx as reverse proxy and the jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion to handle the SSL-Certificate.

Now I have configured SonarQube using the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  ext:
  int:

volumes:
  certs:
  vhosts:
  html:
  postgresql_data:
  postgresql:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:

services:
  nginxproxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    container_name: nginxproxy
    hostname: nginxproxy
    restart:
      unless-stopped
    networks:
      - ext
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./config/my_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/myproxy.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    labels:
      - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy
    environment:
      - SSL_POLICY=Mozilla-Intermediate
  nginxproxy_comp:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginxproxy_comp
    hostname: nginxproxy_comp
    restart:
      unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - nginxproxy
    networks:
      - ext
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:community
    container_name: sonarqube
    hostname: sonarqube
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart:
      unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
    environment:
      - SONAR_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sonarqube
      - SONAR_JDBC_USER=sonarqube
      - SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonarqube
    networks:
      - int
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: db
    hostname: db
    networks:
      - int
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=sonarqube
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonarqube
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart:
      unless-stopped
```

Now when I try to start docker-compose, SonarQube is giving me the following Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@277050dc-org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Can anyone please tell me what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What I see here is the incorrect JDBC URL. It must below

```
SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonarqube
```

Since you have network between containers DB accessible via db

Also, under SonarQube container add below as well

```
privileged: true
```

Check one of my sample project in GitHub

https://github.com/shamith234/sonarqube-9.5-postgres-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml